# First data written in pipeline (is it consistent)

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

If I have this pipeline:

```
echo "bar" | nc localhost 6969 < <(echo "foo")
```

will "foo" always be written to the tcp socket before "bar"? Is there a precedence there that is consistent?

Comment: turns out, "bar" never gets received at all, only "foo" gets received, not sure why

Answer (score 3):

The redirection of the piped data from the first `echo` into `nc` is overridden by the redirection from the process substitution.  This means that `nc` will only ever see the input from the process substitution, i.e. the string `foo`.

More generally, in

```
command1 | command2 <data
```

`command2` will never read `command1`'s output.

To have `nc` read both strings, arrange with them to be delivered together, either with

```
{ echo "foo"; echo "bar"; } | nc localhost 6969
```

or

```
nc localhost 6969 < <( echo "foo"; echo "bar" )
```

Answer (score 3):

In

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

`cmd1` and `cmd2` are started in parallel with `cmd1`'s stdout connected to the writing end of a pipe (or socketpair in ksh93), and `cmd2`'s stdin connected to the other end of that pipe.

In:

```
cmd < file
```

`cmd` is started with `cmd`'s stdin opened on the `file`.

So you can see that

```
cmd1 | cmd2 < file
```

conflicts; you have to choose whether `cmd2`'s stdin is the pipe from `cmd1` or the `file`.

In the above, in most shells, the `<file` takes precedence as the redirection is done *after* (the shell starts 2 processes with the pipe in-between them, and *then* interprets each of the command, including redirections inside each independently)

That means that `cmd2`'s stdin will be `file`, and the pipe `echo` is writing to will have no reader (a broken pipe). So in your case, `bar` will never make it to `nc` and the process running `echo bar` may even get killed if it writes `bar` after the other process has opened the file.

In `zsh` however, with the `multios` option on (and it's on by default), `zsh` detects that you're trying to redirect the same file descriptor (here 0, stdin) twice, and takes it that you meant for the data from both those sources to be sent to `cmd2`, so instead of making `cmd2`'s stdin the pipe from `cmd1` or `file`, it will actually start an internal *feeder* process that reads the data from both sources and sends it (one after the other, via another pipe) to `cmd2`.

```
cmd1 < <(cmd2)
```

is just a case of `cmd1 < file` where `file` is a named pipe (or something that behaves like a named pipe) with `cmd2` writing at the other end, but is otherwise not much different.

Portably, if you want to send the output of  two commands, or send the output of a command and the content of a file to some command, you'd use:

```
{
  cmd1
  cmd2
} | cmd3
```

Or:

```
{
  cmd1
  cat < file
} | cmd2
```

So here:

```
{
  echo bar
  echo foo
} | nc localhost 6969
```

Answer (score 0):

Eh for some reason seems tricky. Maybe you could write something in C, but this solves the problem using node.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const msg = process.argv[2] || process.env.ql_message;

if(!msg){
  console.error('quicklock: no message defined in ql_init_message.');
  process.exit(1);
}

console.log(msg);
process.stdin.resume().pipe(process.stdout);
```

at the command line you use it like so:

```
echo "bar" | initial_message "foo" | nc localhost 6969;
```

initial_message is just logging one thing to stdout, then just sending stdin to stdout as a pass through.

And in this case I def would assume "foo" would always be written before "bar".