# Write to named pipe in pipeline

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I had this:

```
 tail -f "${my_input}" | ql_receiver_lock_holder > "${my_named_pipe}" & disown;
```

but after reading this answer:
[First data written in pipeline (is it consistent)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439245/first-data-written-in-pipeline-is-it-consistent/439253#439253)

I get the feeling that ${my_named_pipe} will never receive any data from the ${my_input} file.

The only way I know how to solve this would be something like this:

```
tail -f "${my_input}" | ql_receiver_lock_holder | while read line; do
   echo "$line" > ${my_named_pipe};
done & disown;
```

is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why? Is q1_receiver_lock_holder (there must be some significance in this name, that I am missing) creating the named-pipe?

Comment: it's supposed to be writing to the named pipe, not creating it

Comment: something might be wrong with the first code snippet, the second code snippet is supposed to be more correct

Comment: "I get the feeling...". "something might be wrong...". Do you have proof of an actual problem that is needing to be solved? If so, please show it to us.

Comment: @Patrick well the question is, given this code: `tail -f "${my_input}" | ql_receiver_lock_holder > "${my_named_pipe}" & disown;` can ${my_named_pipe} ever received data from the tail command? From what I gather the answer is never.

Comment: It depends on what `ql_receiver_lock_holder` does with said data.

Comment: ahh maybe what's happen is that `> "${my_named_pipe}"` is always overwriting the existing named pipe. Is there a way to write to an existing named pipe?

Comment: This question is too abstract, and also too specific. Please show what is happening, and what you expect. Please tell us what `ql_receiver_lock_holder` is: what is the relevance of `ql`, `receiver` and `lock_holder`.

Answer (score 1):

If `my_named_pipe` exists at the start: that is `ql_receiver_lock_holder` does not create it, then it will work, else it will not.

In the examples below I have removed all irrelevant stuff. The question is very generic, therefore so is the answer.

This will work:

```
a-process | another-process > "${my_named_pipe}"
```

This will not:

```
a-process | another-process-that-also-creates-the-pipe > "${my_named_pipe}"
```

## Reason

In the first one there is nothing stopping it from working. The linked question in the question refers to redirecting standard in (not standard out). Like wise `process1 > a-file | process2`, `process2` will not get any input.

In the 2nd example, the pipe can not be connected before it exists. All plumbing must be done before processes start. There is no way for a process to signal do the plumbing now. And could be no way more simple than the process doing it it-self.